# how can i get the values separated by a comma to a array? using java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

i have this static code that will hide/show some combo box but what if i add more category´s ?well if do add more category´s i have to change the code every time

so what i want to do is have a var that will receive several values separated by comma

and them some how it will separate the values and them it will store the values in a array. and now when the user needs to add more category´s i don't have to edit the code.

but how can i separate the values divided by a comma and then add them to a array?

Comment: `'bla,bla,bla'.split(',')` -> `['bla', 'bla', 'bla']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you'll want to have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

And use `var arr = YOURVARIABLE.split(',');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the String.split() function, e.g:

```
var s = '1,2,3,4,5,6';
var values = s.split(',');

console.log(values);
```

For more information see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: in this exemple i need to know what the values of "s" will be?

Comment: You may need to explain a bit further. You have a lot of good answers here to the question you've asked, if there is something more you are trying to achieve then please make it very clear. :)

Comment: They will be strings. '1,2,3,4' split becomes ['1','2','3','4']

Answer (score 0):

You would use the split() method. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
var string = '1,2,3,text,123';
var array = string.split(',');

//array = [1, 2, 3, 'text', 123];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
var testString = "comma,seperated,list";

var stringArr = testString.split(",");
```

the split() method will literally split the string by the delimeter passed to it and return an array of values. in this case our array will be

```
// stringArr = ["comma", "seperated", "list"];
```